# Turbo Assembler (TASM) Undefined symbol error for extrn procedure

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, tasm, unresolved-external

I am working on some Turbo Assembler which I was introduced to in my architecture class. The problem I am working on is using the `extrn` and `include` keywords to access a function/procedure from one ASM file and use it in another one. I included the respective files below and also ran the following commands:

> ```
> tasm file1.asm  
> tasm file2.asm  
> tlink file1.obj+tlink2.obj
> ```

After `tlink` I get the error about `MyProcedure` being an undefined symbol in file2.asm.

**file1.asm**:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
    ; Data declarations go here

.CODE
    ; Code segment

    ; Define the procedure
    MyProcedure PROC
        ; Procedure code goes here
        ; For example:
        MOV AH, 9     ; DOS interrupt to print string
        LEA DX, Msg   ; Load the address of the message
        INT 21h       ; Call DOS interrupt
        RET           ; Return from the procedure
    MyProcedure ENDP

    ; Data section
    Msg DB "Hello, World!$"

END
```

**file1.inc**:

```
; Declare external procedure MyProcedure
EXTRN MyProcedure:NEAR
```

**file2.asm**:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
    ; Data declarations go here

.CODE
    ; Code segment

    ; Include external file
    INCLUDE file1.inc

    ; Main program
    START:
        ; Call the procedure defined in file1.inc
        CALL MyProcedure

        ; Other code goes here

    ; End of main program

END START
```

Comment: Probably because you didn't mark the function as public so that it is available to other modules.

Comment: @MichaelPetch where should I put the public keyword?

Comment: Have you tried using `MyProcedure PROC PUBLIC` instead of `MyProcedure PROC`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I was able to come up with an answer I will put the code together and post two different answers soon. After I test another piece. I figured out where all the keywords go and how I need to compile and link them together. Thanks for your help

Comment: `tlink file1.obj+tlink2.obj` Are you sure this line is correct? Shouldn't it be: `tlink file1.obj+file2.obj`.

Comment: @Sep Roland I was able to use both ways interchangeably and produce the same result. I will just make a note in an updated answer. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out what I was doing. This answer is considered using Borland's 16-bit TASM 5.0 so keep that in mind. I will include two different answers and just remember to use accordingly.

**First way**: Using a reference from an external ASM file.
If you want to reference an external file with a specific procedure, here is an example with instructions:

file1.asm (main file)

```
; Simple program that will use an external call to file external.asm
; The procedure will call a system interrupt
; External procedure that will execute the system interrupt in the program
; Declare at the top here to let the assembler know that this will be referenced outside this file when creating the assembler object

EXTRN myProcedure:PROC
                 
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    ; Data declaration goes here
.code
    ; Code declaration goes here
_start:
    CALL myProcedure   ; calls the myProcedure that will execute the system interrupt

end _start
```

This first file is the main file that is using the externally called procedure *myProcedure*. Seems best practice is to place the `EXTRN` command at the top so the assembler knows.

file2.asm (externally referenced file)

```
; Program that contains the system interrupt command procedure called myProcedure
; Will be externally referenced in main.asm
; 

.MODEL small
.CODE

; This public declaration works like an interface and lets the assembler know that this procedure 
; can be externally referenced and executed by the files that are tlinked with this program respectively

PUBLIC myProcedure
myProcedure PROC NEAR ; Procedure declaration with procedure code for declaration
    ; Procedure code here
    MOV AH, 4Ch
    INT 21h
    RET
myProcedure ENDP

END
```

This file is the external file that will contain the defined procedure *myProcedure*. The `NEAR` keyword just lets the program know to jump inside the segment. In this example, when called in the `main.asm`, it will stay inside the Start segment. If you find the program begins to get larger, you may need to switch to `FAR` and experiment with that keyword instead.

Instructions:

> ```
> tasm file1.asm  
> tasm file2.asm  
> tlink file1.obj file2.obj  
> main.exe (or whatever executable that is spit out)
> ```

---

**Second way**: Using a .INC file that will hold the procedure that will be included at run time in the main .ASM file.

file1.asm (main file)

```
; This program is example on how to use `INCLUDE` keyword in TASM 16-bit program to reference an external procedure, struct, obj, macro, etc
; All it does is call a system interrupt from the respective .INC file. In this case it is main2.inc

.MODEL small
.STACK 100h
.DATA
    ; Data section here

.CODE
        INCLUDE file1.inc ; Contains the procedure I will reference
Start:

        Call myProcedure ; Call the desired procedure.

END Start
```

This main file just has the `INCLUDE` statement that is placed in the `.CODE` segment. Now that the assembler knows to include the file you can see below at the *Start* label where I will call the procedure that is being referenced from file1.inc.

file1.inc (file to be included that contains the procedure)

```
; .INC file that will contain the system interrupt procedure 

PUBLIC myProcedure ; Interface declaration that allows assembler to know that the procedure can be used publicly in the respective file
myProcedure PROC NEAR
    ; Procedure code here
    MOV AH, 4Ch
    INT 21h
    RET
myProcedure ENDP
```

You can see that the .INC works the same way like a hoarder file in C or C++. You just put whatever needs to be referenced there so it can be called in any file at anytime as long as the file that wants to reference included it with the `INCLUDE` statement. In this case as long as file1.asm has the `INCLUDE file1.inc` we can use the procedure *myProcedure*.

Instructions:

> ```
> tasm file1.asm
> tlink file1.obj
> main.exe (or whatever executable that is spit out)
> ```

You can see this second set of instructions differs a little bit considering we do not need to tasm or tlink a second file. You can run the program pretty straightforward.

---

I hope this helps anyone else on this assembler journey. Please comment and ask questions. I will do my best to get back or I hope someone is able to help.

Comment: In file1.inc you wrote: "PUBLIC myProcedure ; interface declaration that allows assembler to know that the procedure can be used publicly in the respective file". Given that the 'respective file' (as you named it) contains "Include file1.inc", which is a textual inclusion, there's no need for a PUBLIC declaration. At least not as a solution to the "undefined symbol" from the original question.

Comment: For compatibility with MASM, your TASM allows both `EXTERN` and `EXTRN`. Be consistent, chose one and stick with it (at least in the same source text). And for readability, (so these special commands stand out), I think you should capitalize them. On the other hand you should not be capitalizing normal instruction like `call`. Currently you are doing that: see `CALL`, `Call`, `MOV`, `INT`, ...

Comment: @Sep Roland I can I only used `EXTRN` in the example files given here unless I missed where I used `EXTERN` but also I think that is a great point about the interchangeability of the `EXTRN` and `EXTERN` keyword in TASM and MASM. It is just a habit that I have of capitalizing the instruction sets from my time in uni. It doesn't matter for the most part it is assembled all the same.

Comment: @Sep Roland in regards to your first point what most likely was the solution was the fact that when I was using two .ASM files I was not assembling both, then thinking, and lastly running the .exe file. What I was doing was assembly, tlink, and execution on one file that was calling the outside reference, thus the reason the assembler gave me the error.